# Does CUDA toolkit work with ubuntu 11.04

Tags: cuda, ubuntu-11.04

I just installed the latest version of ubuntu and cuda toolkit. I was curious if the cuda toolkit is compatible with ubuntu 11.04

Comment: What is *this* and what is *here*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work just fine. In fact, already since the 4.0 RC versions people have reported that they successfully used CUDA on Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: This is where I do all of my CUDA development & run my deployed solutions.  It works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm that toolkit 4.1 works too on ubuntu 11.04